# jQuery actions on ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have loaded some data into a boostrap.

```
$(".open_modal").live('click', function () {
    var $url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    var $title = $(this).attr('title');
    var $modal_data = $('<div class="modal" id="my_modal"><div class="modal-header"><button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button><h3><img src="/assets/imgs/loading.gif" /> Loading....</h3></div><div id="modal_content"></div></div>')
        $modal_data.modal({
            show: true,
            backdrop: 'static'
        });
       $modal_data.find("#modal_content").load($url,function(){         
            $modal_data.find("h3").text($title);
    });
    return false;
});
```

The content I am loading contains a form...

I am trying to fire a jquery code block the submit event.

```
$("body").delegate("#post_status_frm", 'submit', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $status = $("#shout_field").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/do/post_status.asp",
        data:  $this.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data === 'true') {
                $("#my_modal").modal('hide');
                $("#activity").load('/content/activity.asp');
            } else {
                alert(data);
            }
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

But its not working?

I tried throwing up an `alert("")` on the event to check it is firing. it isn't.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Are you sure that an element with id of post_status_frm is available on the dom ? did you try to look with firebug if their id's are really working.

Comment: Yeah the form with that ID is appearing in the console.

Comment: Have you checked whether **post_status.asp** is returning valid JSON?

Comment: @Coby post_status.asp doesn't return json it simply returns true or an error message.

Comment: Can we see the exact output from post_status.asp, please?

Answer (score 0):

If **post_status.asp** is simply returning a header response of "200 OK" with an empty "response body", the `data` variable is going to return a value of `null`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/do/post_status.asp",
    data:  $this.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data, data === null); // Output: null true
        $("#my_modal").modal('hide');
        $("#activity").load('/content/activity.asp');
    }
});
```

If you want **post_status.asp** to respond with actual **[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)** data, they need to be in "key-value pairs".